# Validating with all requests

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I have this form:

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="{{url('/books')}}">
                {!! csrf_field() !!}
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <label>Book Name:</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name"><br>
                    <label>Pages:</label>  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="pages"><br>
                    <label>Price in Rs:</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" name="price"><br>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><br>
                </div>
                </form>
```

And i'm trying to validate if all the form fields are set and not null. similar to `isset()`. but, else statement is not executed even if submitted without entering values in any inputs. Isn't `$request->all()` supposed to do so.

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->all())
        {
            $book=new Book();
            $book->name=$request->name;
            $book->pages=$request->pages;
            $book->price=$request->price;
            if($book->save())
            {
                return Response::json(true);
            }
            else
            {
                return Response::json(false);   
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return "norequest";
        }
    }
```

Comment: `$request->all()` gives you all the inputs. It doesn't validate the inputs. Check https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation for how to validate inputs

Comment: @Saumini if $request->all() is not giving all input values, shouldn't else statement be executed?

Comment: `$request->all` gives array of inputs with empty values. Something like `['name' => '', 'pages' => '', 'price' => '']`. Print the request and see

Answer (score 0):

You can use the  `ValidatesRequests` trait of Laravel.

The code in your `store`  might look like this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'pages' => 'required',
        'price' => 'required'
    ]);

    // the rest of your code goes here....


}
```

Here, the above code will accomplish what you want. So, no need to use `$request->all()` to check if all fields are set and not null.

Hope this helps.